# Multiple ExpressJS(Nodejs) Apps on Same Box

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've been searching for a straightforward way of doing this that wouldn't involve editing every single users' host file.

I'm going to have a couple internal apps for employees to use that are going to be hosted on the same Windows Server.  I want to use a default port, but want them to be separated out so, for example if you go to

- www.host.com/longrunners

you get the longrunners page.  If you go to:

- www.host.com/databaseMove

you get the database move page.

I'm aware that I could do this by having all of the code within the same server.js file, using app.get('/longrunners',function(res,req){}) etc for each separate app -- but I'm hoping there is a more modular solution.  Maye a way to have one master server.js file that references the different apps?

Thanks!

Comment: There's more than one way to do it - express does support virtual applications, and that's one way but I'd probably recommend using nginx to just proxy to the correct app.

Comment: By virtual applications I mean using something like https://github.com/expressjs/vhost

Comment: Why not just make them different endpoints in the same app? I must be missing something.

Comment: Making them different endpoints in the same app just seems messy.  If thats the best / most straightforward way to do it, then so be it.